# How to provide updates to the app deployed as a VM solution on Google Cloud Marketplace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wish to offer my application as a [VM solution](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm) on Google Cloud Marketplace. However I haven't figured out how to provide updates to my application. As far I as I know, I need to deprecate the existing image and update it with a new one. I am not sure how existing customers will get the updated application. Could somebody please help me understand this ?

I have referred to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/969608/updating-a-solution-listed-on-google-cloud-marketplace) question, but it mostly deals with Kubernetes solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updates in your image, once deployed, aren't dependent on Marketplace. As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/#updating_a_software_package)

> To update your existing deployment of a software package, you must redeploy the software package from Cloud Marketplace.

The workaround would be having the update mechanism shipped at OS level instead.

This approach would be closer to what happens with Kubernetes images, as the system itself (K8s) is designed to auto-deploy (e.g. [using Helm](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/kubernetes-solutions/create-app-package#overview)), which is not necessarily the same scenario for regular VMs.